# scala gson array parsing

Tags: scala, gson

Please explain whats wrong with the code, I'm getting the output as {} empty. How should I get the json output.

```
val values = (1 to 10).toList
 val topic = "linkedlists"
 val gson = new GsonBuilder().create()
 val output=gson.toJson(values,classOf[List[Int]])
 println(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*because java.*

you can use `java.util.List` not `scala.collection.immutable.List`

example,

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val list = (1 to 10).asJava

val gson = new GsonBuilder().create()
gson.toJson(list, classOf[java.util.List[Int]]) shouldBe "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]"
```